# Blender on BOINC

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I would like to render a Blender image on the Boinc server.

Are there any specific documents to follow to do that?  I already have installed Boinc server in Debian Linux 8.  In the same machine I installed Blender as well.
I am not sure how to continue after that.  Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Comment: See https://burp.renderfarming.net. As any free distributed render farm there won't be any result straight away, it will depend on how much you render back. This is not Blender question though rather than asking about render farm